# SQL Server : return string procedure INITCAP

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

This is what I've done.

```
create proc INITCAP(@string varchar(30))
as
begin
    SET @string = UPPER(LEFT(@string,1)) + LOWER(RIGHT(@string, LEN(@string) -1))
end

declare @lastname varchar
set @lastname = exec INITCAP 'MILLER'

declare @firstname varchar
set @firstname = exec INITCAP 'StEvE'

UPDATE Employee SET firstname = @firstname, lastname = @lastname WHERE empID = 7934
```

I keep getting the errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure INITCAP, Line 97
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'exec'.
>   Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure INITCAP, Line 100
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'exec'.

What shall I do? I want the procedure `INITCAP` to work as it does in Oracle: to return a name like: "Steve", "Miller"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution #1** (I wouln't use this solution)

You could use OUTPUT parameters thus:

```
create proc INITCAP(@string varchar(30) OUTPUT)
as
begin
    SET @string = UPPER(LEFT(@string,1)) + LOWER(SUBSTRING(@string, 2, 8000))
end
go 

declare @lastname varchar
set @lastname = 'MILLER'
exec INITCAP @lastname OUTPUT

declare @firstname varchar
set @firstname = 'StEvE'
exec INITCAP @firstname OUTPUT
```

**Solution #2**: Instead, **I would choose** to create an inline function thus:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Capitalize1(@string varchar(30))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
SELECT UPPER(LEFT(@string,1)) + LOWER(SUBSTRING(@string, 2, 8000)) AS Result;
```

Usage:

```
UPDATE e 
SET firstname = cap.Result
FROM Employee e
CROSS APPLY dbo.Capitalize1(e.firstname) cap;
```

**Solution #3**: Another option could be a scalar function `with schemabinding` option (for performance reasons):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Capitalize2(@string varchar(30))
RETURNS VARCHAR(30)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN UPPER(LEFT(@string,1)) + LOWER(SUBSTRING(@string, 2, 8000));
END;
```

Usage:

```
UPDATE Employee
SET firstname = dbo.Capitalize2(firstname);
```

Comment: Solution #2 should give you the best performance especially when you have to update more than one person.

Comment: yes , tried with function but didn't get it. now as u showed me i surely will use it as a function! thanks!

Comment: im still getting an error: 'INITCAP' is not a recognized built-in function name. using the 3 solution ( changed name of func to INITCAP)

Comment: UPDATE Employee SET firstname =INITCAP('SteVe')  this is what i am doing

Comment: When you call a UDF you should use also the schema name: `dbo.Capitalize1(...)` (for example) and not just function name `Capitalize(...)`

Comment: Use `SET ... = dbo.INITCAP('SteVe')`

Comment: Note: instead of `LOWER(RIGHT(@string, LEN(@string) -1))` I used `LOWER(SUBSTRING(@string, 2, 8000))` because of LEN function (example: try `SELECT LEN('A   ')`)

Comment: Thanks! "dbo." worked  , i am still new to this functionalities, my brain is still set to other programming languages.. as the function it self is just something i tried and i'll make it better and simplier. I got another question for you: I get an error when i execute the whole sql (including the create function) but if i execute only the update.... then it works.. Why is that?

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure INITCAP, Line 99
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UPDATE'.

Comment: I only get this error when I execute THE WHOLE code including the function, but if I SELECT the update query then I get no error

Comment: Why procedure INITCAP has more than 5 lines ? It should ends with `end`, just before `go` (I added the line with `go` now). Replace `create procedure` with `alter procedure`, select the source of this SP from `alter procedure INITCAP` to `... end go` in SSMS and then click on `Execute` (F5) button.

Comment: The lines are because i got other queries /* commented upside */ Thanks that ALTER really helped me!!

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a stored Proc for this ??? I would do something like this a UDF would do the job just fine i think....

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_SomeFunction (@String VARCHAR(30))
RETURNS VARCHAR(30)
AS
BEGIN
     DECLARE @rtnString VARCHAR(30);
    SET @rtnString = UPPER(LEFT(@string,1)) + LOWER(RIGHT(@string, LEN(@string) -1))
     RETURN(@rtnString);
END;
```

You can call this function in your **SELECT** statement , Having a proc doing the same job doesnt give you this flexibility

**UPDATE**

```
UPDATE Employee 
SET firstname = dbo.udf_SomeFunction (firstname)
, lastname = dbo.udf_SomeFunction (lastname)
WHERE empID = 7934
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a function to achieve what you need and use a syntax that you want in setting the variables. Please not that you have to put `GO` between function creation and the rest.

```
create function INITCAP(@string varchar(30))
returns varchar(30)
as
begin
    return UPPER(LEFT(@string,1)) + LOWER(RIGHT(@string, LEN(@string) -1))
end

go

declare @lastname varchar
set @lastname = dbo.INITCAP('MILLER')

declare @firstname varchar
set @firstname = dbo.INITCAP('StEvE')

UPDATE Employee SET firstname = @firstname, lastname = @lastname WHERE empID = 7934
```