# using sql query to capitalize the fields

Tags: sql, uppercase

I just have this question and was wondering if it can be achieved via SQL query

I have in my db name field as - SAM MATHEWS M and i wish to convert it as

Sam Mathews M

is there a way to achive this via SQL query. I'm aware of writing a PHP code to achive it by traversing across chars, but need to know if this is a possibility...

thanks,
Samuel Mathews.

Comment: The same methodology you would use in PHP can be used in SQL - although more ineffective as it's not really what the SQL is good for. But there are functions to identify patterns, make substrings, and replace those substrings with lower case letters. However the exact syntax can vary from database engine/system to system - so which one are you running on?

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339538/sql-server-return-string-procedure-initcap

Comment: i use the normal web server - phpmyadmin server. let me know if you require more info.
thanks!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

You are not telling us, which database you use.

So **PostgreSQL** or **Oracle** have a capitalization method `initcap`.

```
-- PostgreSQL
select initcap('SAM MATHEWS M')

-- Oracle
select initcap('SAM MATHEWS M') from dual
```

This prints the expected result

```
Sam Mathews M
```

For **SQLServer** there not seems to be such an easy solution and you have to go for a UDF: [SQL: capitalize first letter only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290754/sql-capitalize-first-letter-only).

Comment: thanks, i will check on these tonight and wil keep you updated. 

thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

i know this is disgusting and not genaric to a great extend but i think there isnt anothor work around for this

```
declare @string as nvarchar(20) = 'SAM MATHEWS M'
declare @1 as nvarchar(20) = PARSENAME(REPLACE(@string, ' ', '.'), 1)
declare @2 as nvarchar(20) = PARSENAME(REPLACE(@string, ' ', '.'), 2)
declare @3 as nvarchar(20) = PARSENAME(REPLACE(@string, ' ', '.'), 3)

SELECT Upper(left(@3,1)) + LOWER(RIGHT(@3,LEN(@3)-1))
+ ' '
+ Upper(left(@2,1)) + LOWER(RIGHT(@2,LEN(@2)-1))
+' '
+Upper(left(@1,1)) + LOWER(RIGHT(@1,LEN(@1)-1))
```

this is for MsSql server

Answer (score -2):

This is a false problem. You're asking your database to do what your view is supposed to do in your web app (or whatever client you're designing).

If you're a DBA, talk to your developers. Talking solve a lot of problems.

**My solution** : do it in your view. Leave your database alone with more important task than esthetics.